# Multiple Django apps under same domain

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to set up two Django applications locally at subdirectories under the same domain, e.g.:

```
http://127.0.0.1/en/
http://127.0.0.1/jp/
```

Here is a snippet of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
WSGIDaemonProcess khdx_wsgi user=galdosd group=galdosd maximum-requests=10000
WSGIScriptAlias /khdx /home/galdosd/khdxweb/rel/khdx/apache/django.wsgi
<Location /khdx>
    WSGIProcessGroup khdx_wsgi
</Location>

WSGIDaemonProcess sauron_wsgi user=galdosd group=galdosd maximum-requests=10000
WSGIScriptAlias /sauron /home/galdosd/finalsauronweb/django-root/apache/django.wsgi
<Location /sauron>
    WSGIProcessGroup sauron_wsgi
</Location>
```

The problem I am facing is that all the urls are working relative to `127.0.0.1` e.g. `127.0.0.1/accounts` or `127.0.0.1/login` instead of `127.0.0.1/en/accounts` or `127.0.0.1/en/login`.

Initially when i had just one Django application running at 127.0.0.1, all things were working fine since i had my `WSGIScriptAlias` directed at `/` instead of `/en` or `/jp`.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the apps to appear as:

```
http://127.0.0.1/en/
http://127.0.0.1/jp/
```

then you should be using:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess khdx_wsgi user=galdosd group=galdosd maximum-requests=10000
WSGIScriptAlias /en /home/galdosd/khdxweb/rel/khdx/apache/django.wsgi
<Location /en>
    WSGIProcessGroup khdx_wsgi
</Location>

WSGIDaemonProcess sauron_wsgi user=galdosd group=galdosd maximum-requests=10000
WSGIScriptAlias /jp /home/galdosd/finalsauronweb/django-root/apache/django.wsgi
<Location /jp>
    WSGIProcessGroup sauron_wsgi
</Location>
```

Have no idea where the sub URL mount points of /khdx and /sauron are coming from, but it isn't going to yield what you want.

I would actually further simplify the above to:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess khdx_wsgi user=galdosd group=galdosd maximum-requests=10000
WSGIScriptAlias /en /home/galdosd/khdxweb/rel/khdx/apache/django.wsgi process-group=khdx_wsgi application-group=%{GLOBAL}

WSGIDaemonProcess sauron_wsgi user=galdosd group=galdosd maximum-requests=10000
WSGIScriptAlias /jp /home/galdosd/finalsauronweb/django-root/apache/django.wsgi process-group=sauron_wsgi application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

Just make sure you are using mod_wsgi 3.0 or later and not some ancient 2.X version.

Also make sure that in your code you are using the correct template macros and code functions to calculate URLs properly when needing to fill them out in responses else they can be missing the mount point.

Also use the appropriate means for the Django version being used to fill out the mount point in login/logout URLs. Older Django versions would require you in the settings file to explicitly have en and jp as part of the setting for the login/logout URL. These days there is some magic function you can use which will automatically prefix them with the mount point so you aren't embedding knowledge of the mount point in the login/logout URL path in settings.

So use that configuration and then if still have issues then restate your issue based on that configuration.

Comment: Thanks Graham.I made the changes as u suggested. But the issue still persists. I'm using mod_wsgi 3.x and Django is 1.4.  Also in my settings file , LOGIN_URL = '/login' . Do i need to specify the mount point somewhere else in my settings file as well ?

Comment: Since you are using Django 1.4, you will need to add the /en or /jp prefix to LOGIN_URL and LOGOUT_URL settings. In Django 1.5 they have some mechanism where you can avoid that. I am not sure how it works, but I think you specify the name of a named URL pattern instead of a URL and when required the URL is calculated from that and will include the prefix automatically, which is passed into Django in SCRIPT_NAME in the WSGI environ dictionary. FWIW, the Django 1.5 documentation is at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#login-url and it alludes to the change.

Comment: Hi Graham. I added the the prefixes to LOGIN_URL.
But the problem still remains.
e.g for 127.0.0.1/en and 127.0.0.1/jp , sites are opening up.
But when i open up a link  with an href say /demo on en site, the link opens up at 127.0.0.1/demo instead of 127.0.0.1/en/demo. What am i missing ?

Comment: In templates you need to ensure you are using the 'url' tag to generate the correct full path for the URL. You should not just include a raw '/demo' in the page. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: If generating the path in code rather than a template, use functions in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/urlresolvers/

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for separate applications here. You can implement language-based views the way you want by using [language prefix in Django URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns).

Comment: Actually they are separate sites. They are not identical and have different views as well.

Comment: If the views differ, it's not a problem, as long as the underlying functionalities are the same. You can keep two templates into the application folder and have the same controller render one or the other based on the current language.

Comment: If so, I'd say that offering different functionalities under the same name is very confusing for the user. I mean, I'd expect `foo.bar/jp/baz/` to be the Japanese translation of `foo.bar/en/baz/`, not an unrelated site.

Comment: Actually /en and /jp i mentioned above were just indicatory. They have different functionality in all...